# C++ count the number of words in a string that end in 'y' or 'z'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that looks at the last letter of each word in a single string and determines if it ends in y or z and count it.

For example:

"fez day" -> 2

"day fyyyz" -> 2

Everything I've looked up uses what looks to be arrays, but I don't know how to use those yet. I'm trying to figure out how to do it using for loops.

I honestly don't know where to start. I feel like some of my smaller programs could be used to help this, but I'm struggling in trying to figure out how to combine them.

This code counts the amount of words in a string:

```
int words = 0;
bool connectedLetter;
   for (auto c : s)
   {
      if (c == ' ')
      {
        connectedLetter = false; 
      }
      if ( c != ' ' && connectedLetter == false)
      {
         ++words;
         connectedLetter = true;
      }
```

and it might be useful to try and figure out how to get the code to see separate words.

I've used this program to count the amount of vowels in the entire program:

```
int vowels{0};
for (auto c : s)
{
   if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' 
   || c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U')
   {
      ++vowels;
   }
}
```

and then I've done a small program to see every other letter in a string

```
 auto len = s.size();
   
   for (auto i = 0; i < len; i = i + 2)
   {
      result += s.at(i);
   }
```

I feel like I know the concepts behind it, but its configuring it together which is stopping me

Comment: We can't do your homework for you.  Can you show us some code you have tried?

Comment: What about something like "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday." Is that 0, or 3?

Comment: @Tas I'm pretty sure that would be 3! Because I'm looking at only the last letter per word

Comment: It isn't necessarily looking for words, but parts of strings that end in 'y' or 'z'? Maybe a place to start is by looking for the desired letters first, and not the white space that separates words.

Answer (score 4):

You may also use existing C++ functions that are dedicated to do, what you want.

The solution is to take advantage of basic IOstream functionalities. You may know that the extractor operator `>>` will extract words from an stream (like `std::cin` or any other stream) until it hits the next white space.

So reading words is simple:

```
std::string word{}; std::cin >> word;
```

will read a complete word from `std::cin`.

OK, we have a `std::string` and no stream. But here C++ helps you with the `std::istringstream`. This will convert a `std::string` to a stream object. You can then use all iostream functionalities with this `stringstream`.

Then, for counting elements, following a special requirement, we have a standard algorithm from the C++ library: `std::count_if`.

It expects a begin and an end iterator. And here we simply using the `std::istream_iterator` which will call the extractor operator `>>` for all strings that are in the stream.

WIth a Lambda, given to the `std::count_if`, we check, if a word meets the required condition.

We will get then a very compact piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    // test string
    std::string testString{ "day fyyyz" };

    // We want to extract words from the string, so, convert string to stream.
    std::istringstream iss{ testString };

    // count words, meeting a special condition
    std::cout << std::count_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), {},
        [](const std::string& s) { return s.back() == 'y' || s.back() == 'z'; });

    return 0;
}
```

Of course there are tons of other possible solutions.

---

**Edit**

Pete Becker asked for a more flexible solution. Also here C++ offers a dedicated functionality. The [std::sregex_token_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator).

Here we can specify any word pattern with a regex and the simply get or count the matches.

An even simpler piece of code is the result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

const std::regex re{ R"(\w+[zy])" };

int main() {
    // test string
    std::string s{ "day, fyyyz, abc , zzz" };

    // count words, meeting a special condition
    std::cout << std::vector(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re), {}).size();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty good explanation. +1. Now, for bonus points, make it work for `"day, fyyz"`. <g> (That seems to be beyond the scope of the original question)

Comment: @PeteBecker: Added . . .

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to use an array (or something similar, like a `string`) it's probably easiest to just use two `int`s. For simplicity, let's call them `current` and `previous`. You'll also need a `count`, which you'll want to initialize to 0.

1. Start by initializing both to `EOF`.
2. Read a character into `current`.
3. If current is a space or EOF (well, anything you don't consider part of a word), and previous is `z` or previous is `y`, increment count.
4. If `current` is EOF, print out `count`, and you're done.
5. Copy the value in `current` into `previous`.
6. Go back to step 2.

Comment: Thank you for answering! But i fear I have no clue what EOF is?

Comment: @Michele: It stands for "End Of File"--whatever you get to signal that you've reached the end of the file (and with C-style I/O, it's literally named `EOF`).

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` is much smarter than many people realize. In particular, it has member functions [`find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of), `find_first_not_of`, `find_last_of`, and `find_last_not_of` that are very helpful for simple parsing. I'd approach it like this:

```
std::string str = "fez day"; // for example

std::string targets = "yz";
int target_count = 0;
char delims = ' ';
std::string::pos_type pos = str.find_first_not_of(delims);
while (pos < str.length()) {
    pos = str.find_first_of(delims, pos);
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        pos = str.length();
    if (targets.find(str[pos-1] != std::string::npos)
        ++target_count;
    pos = str.find_first_not_of(delims, pos);
}
std::cout << target_count << '\n';
```

Now, if I need to change this to accommodate comma-separated words, I just change

```
char delims = ' ';
```

to

```
std::string delims = " ,";
```

or to

```
const char* delims = " ,"; // my preference
```

and if I need to change the characters that I'm looking for, just change the contents of `targets`. (In fact, I'd use `const char* targets = "xy";` and search with `std::strchr`, which reduces overhead a bit, but that's not particularly important.)